# Microsoft Graph checkMemberGroups delegated permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am developing an app, where I want to check whether a user belongs to a security group. For the same, I have added the below code to my startup.cs for logging the user in.

> ```
>         services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(
>         options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
>
>         services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme,options =>
>         {
>             options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
>             options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;   
>         });
> ```

Thus I am able to make user logging successfully, I have taken delegated permission also
[image]

Now as per checkMemberGroups [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I need an Authorization token for calling the same.

So could anyone tell how to generate the access token required for the same?

Comment: Checking - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user as of now.

Comment: The link you provided is correct